# Issue with OpenCV 3.0 - Recording Video memory leak

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, ios8, opencv3.0

Sorry, for an old question but I nothing found helful for me. I'm developing an iOS app using OpenCV 3.0 framework.

I'm using cvVideoCamera delgate to record video but as I set `_cvVideoCam.recordVideo = YES;`, it always gives me memory warning error. 
If I set `cvVideoCam,recordVideo = YES;`, Then there is not any memory warning but also the output url always shows (null) at location, on recording finish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    please check your

    -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer.....

     for - 
                                                     withPresentationTime:lastSampleTime] ) 
    {
                         NSLog(@"Video Writing Error");
                     }
                    if (pixelBuffer != nullptr)
                        CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
                 }

             }

because, in some of earlier version OpenCV forgot to release memory upon each append operation to MPEG4 output. May be its your need.
```